# DocumentClient CreateDocumentQuery async

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

Why is there no async version of `CreateDocumentQuery`?

This method for example could have been async:

```
    using (var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), authorizationKey, _connectionPolicy))
    {
        List<Property> propertiesOfUser =
            client.CreateDocumentQuery<Property>(_collectionLink)
                .Where(p => p.OwnerId == userGuid)
                .ToList();

        return propertiesOfUser;
    }
```

Comment: I think that `CreateDocumentQuery` simply creates a query and does not execute it. You could probably use `ToListAsync` instead of `ToList` to execute the query asynchronously.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Good query,

Just try below code to have it in async fashion.

DocumentQueryable.CreateDocumentQuery method creates a query for documents under a collection.

```
 // Query asychronously.
using (var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), authorizationKey, _connectionPolicy))
{
     var propertiesOfUser =
        client.CreateDocumentQuery<Property>(_collectionLink)
            .Where(p => p.OwnerId == userGuid)
            .AsDocumentQuery(); // Replaced with ToList()


while (propertiesOfUser.HasMoreResults) 
{
    foreach(Property p in await propertiesOfUser.ExecuteNextAsync<Property>())
     {
         // Iterate through Property to have List or any other operations
     }
}


}
```

Answer (score 8):

Based on [Kasam Shaikh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338131/documentclient-createdocumentquery-async/39346229#39346229) I've created ToListAsync extensions

```
  public static async Task<List<T>> ToListAsync<T>(this IDocumentQuery<T> queryable)
        {
            var list = new List<T>();
            while (queryable.HasMoreResults)
            {   //Note that ExecuteNextAsync can return many records in each call
                var response = await queryable.ExecuteNextAsync<T>();
                list.AddRange(response);
            }
            return list;
        }
        public static async Task<List<T>> ToListAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
        {
            return await query.AsDocumentQuery().ToListAsync();
        }
```

You can use it

```
var propertiesOfUser = await 
            client.CreateDocumentQuery<Property>(_collectionLink)
                .Where(p => p.OwnerId == userGuid)
                .ToListAsync()
```

Note that [request to have CreateDocumentQuery async is open on github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/287)